# Macro Excel Cognos 8

Tags: excel, cognos-8, vba

The Macro Excel pointe in Cognos 8 Cube. The cube is published in the server of the company.
I want to make these process local . Please check and advice

Answer (score 0):

NOTE-Cognos 8 is unsupported- highly suggest you upgrade to 10 as soon as feasible. 
To clarify- you want to build this cube locally? On your desktop? Depending on size and structure it can take up all your local resources. 
I suggest this-
1. Build the cube on the server and copy it to your destination.
d:\Cognos\PowerCubes\Build, then to publish them- copy them to another directory d:\Cognos\PowerCubes\Live

use the windows copy command i.e. copy d:\Cognos\PowerCubes\Build\yourcube.mdc d:\Cognos\PowerCubes\Live /Y /B

2. Local- build the cube using task scheduler on your local machine.

HTH

Comment: Many thanks for your response . Actually I build mycube.mdc  locally but the publish is in server . I want the diffrents steps to take to publish the cube locally .Hence , acces to cube through macro excel.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I build mycube.mdc locally but the publish is in server . I want the diffrents steps to take to publish the cube locally .Hence , access to cube through macro excel.